# TrueCrypt Container remember keys on board but not shift on/off

Tags: passwords, truecrypt, password-generation

I have some really old TrueCrypt Containers. I think I remember the keys and order that they were typed on the keyboard, but not where shift was held down. So I think I can create a dictionary file but I was wondering if anyone knows of a good generator that can take keyboard keys in a specific order and spit out all the possibilities with shift added. It's a 20 character passphrase...